# If a server calls an API, what IP will the API detect?

Tags: api, http, http-headers, ip-address

Consider the case where there exists a simple client-server web application where the client sends requests to the server. If the server sends a request to an external API, what IP and header values will be detected by the API? The ones of the client that first send the request to the server, or the ones of the server?

Comment: The one of the server.

Answer (score 0):

Only the actual IP that makes the request will be visible to the API. So if there is a chain of requests, only the last request IP will be accessible to the receiving party.